# C++ library called from C code: access violation reading location (KernelBase.dll)

Tags: c++, c, dll, wrapper, mixing

I'm getting a "access violation reading location" expection in quite a complicated scenario. Let me explain. I have a C code which links a static c++ library using a wrapper. This library uses another static library which links a dll. To make it a little more clear I'll try to depict it:

Can.c ---> calls ---> Wrapper.cpp (a wrapper for the c++ library)

Wrapper.cpp ---> calls ---> Lib_For_Wrapping.lib (api for different hw types)

Lib_For_Wrapping.lib ---> calls functions from ---> EG_presos_PAL.dll (which is linked by a static library EG_presos_PAL.lib)

Now, when the function for opening the driver and accessing hw device is called. I get the above mentioned exception.

```
/* Open the driver, access the hardware device. */
palRet = PAL_Startup(
    &m_palSession,
    m_palHwType,
    "0",
    m_palTtcFile,
    true,
    true);
if(palRet) {
    m_talSession    = PAL_NO_SESSION;
    m_currentStatus = Can::BUSSTATUS_DRIVERERROR;
    CIFERROR("PAL_Startup() failed with error code: " << static_cast<int>(palRet));
    return false;
} else {
    ++sm_numInstances;
}
```

The declaration for this function looks like this:

```
PAL_Startup(PAL_SessionHandleType * pSessionHandle,
        PAL_ConnectionType eConnectionType,
        const char * sDeviceName,
        const char * sTtcFile,
        PAL_Boolean bWaitUntilReady,
        PAL_Boolean bCleanStartup);
```

Unfortunatelly, I don't have access to the implementation but to my knowledge I do not try to dereference any null pointers. Call to this function is as far as I can see since the implementation is in the dll. The last callstack entry is DeviceIoControl in KernelBase.dll.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to work with the author of this library to get help.  Send him a small repro project that exhibits this problem.  He'll either fix a bug in his code or tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: I've talked to the author of the library but so far to no avail. But I have an idea that I'd like to run by you, guys. Could it be caused by ABI incompatibility? My project is compiled using VS (CTP 2013) and the library most likely uses minGW. One thing that agrues against it is that the exception isn't raised immediately after calling the first function in the dll. I can see several entries on the callstack that stem from the EG_presos_PAL.dll. Or do you guys think it's still possible?